# Is it possible to initialize array in batch in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I know I can write

```
a := Object()
a[1] := "textA"
a[2] := "textB"
a[3] := "textC"
```

Can I write something like

```
a := {"textA", "textB", "textC"}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an **indexed array** using the bracket syntax:

```
a := ["textA", "textB", "textC"]
```

or the array creation function:

```
a := Array{"textA", "textB", "textC"}
```

An indexed array is an **object** representing a list of items, numbered 1 and up. In this example, the value "textA" is stored in object key 1, the value "textB" in object key 2 and the value "textC" in object key 3.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s7